# c# serialization ascii confusion

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, string, ascii

Here's the code.

```
[Serializable]
public class HostedGame
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public int UID { get; set; }

    public String Name { get; set; }

    public Boolean Available { get; set; }

    public String Description { get; set; }

    public List<int> Users { get; set; }

    public int Port { get; set; }

    public HostedGame(int uid, String name, String description, int port)
    {
        UID = uid;
        Name = name;
        Description = description;
        Available = true;
        Port = port;
        Users = new List<int>();
    }

    public int CompareTo(Object obj)
    {
        int result = 1;
        if(obj != null && obj is HostedGame)
        {
            HostedGame w = obj as HostedGame;
            result = this.ID.CompareTo(w.ID);
        }
        return result;
    }

    static public int Compare(HostedGame x, HostedGame y)
    {
        int result = 1;
        if(x != null && y != null)
        {
            result = x.CompareTo(y);
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static HostedGame DeSerialize(byte[] data)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(data);
        BinaryFormatter bff = new BinaryFormatter();
        return (HostedGame)bff.Deserialize(ms);
    }

    public static byte[] Serialize(HostedGame obj)
    {
        BinaryFormatter bff = new BinaryFormatter();
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        bff.Serialize(ms, obj);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

The code bellow doesn't seem to work right:

```
HostedGame hs = new HostedGame(12,"Name", "Description", 8088);
String s = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(HostedGame.Serialize(hs));
HostedGame HACK = HostedGame.DeSerialize(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s));
```

`HACK.Port` for some reason comes out being 7999?

When I just do this...

```
HostedGame HACK = HostedGame.DeSerialize(HostedGame.Serialize(hs));
```

It works fine.

### So, what I'm asking is

1. Why am I getting a wrong value?
2. Is there a better way to convert the bytes to a string and back again?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot use `Encoding.ASCII.GetString` to convert any byte array to a string. You are losing some data when you do this. Use `Convert.ToBase64String` instead. This one will make a string from any byte sequence without losing the data.

```
HostedGame hs = new HostedGame(12,"Name", "Description", 8088);
String s = Convert.ToBase64String(HostedGame.Serialize(hs));
HostedGame HACK= HostedGame.DeSerialize(Convert.FromBase64String(s));
```

Here is an example, that shows how using `Encoding.ASCII` loses the data.

```
var testBytes = new byte[] { 250, 251, 252 };
var text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(testBytes);
var bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(result); // will be 63, 63, 63
```

Comment: Explain please. What makes that a better option?

Comment: It is not a better option. It is a working option. Yours is not, so it is implicitly better :)

Answer (score 3):

Binary serialization generates a byte array which is not (necessarily) a valid string in any encoding.

When you try to read it as ASCII text, the ASCII decoder will convert any invalid bytes (> 128) into `?` characters.
Therefore, when you turn it back into ASCII bytes, you end up with a different set of bytes.

In short, **don't treat binary data as ASCII**, or as any other text encoding.

If you need to send binary data as plain text, use Base64 to safely convert it to text.